# pivot_wider on multiple key:value pairs

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a registration database, that looks like that

```
reg <- tibble(
  name = c("John","Bill","Chuck"),
  email= c("john@john.com","bill@acme.com","chuck@someplace.org"),
  option1=c("meal","meal","drink"),
  value1=c("vegetarian","vegetarian","beer"),
  option2=c(NA,"drink","room"),
  value2=c(NA,"beer","single"),
  option3=c(NA,"room",NA),
  value3=c(NA,"single",NA)
)
```

in other words, each of the three options (more in the real data, of course) can end up in different columns, and each registrant may have none, one or many options.

This is not a very sensible format, and I would like to make it more practical, like this:

```
  name  email               meal       drink room  
  <chr> <chr>               <chr>      <chr> <chr> 
1 John  john@john.com       vegetarian NA    NA    
2 Bill  bill@acme.com       vegetarian beer  single
3 Chuck chuck@someplace.org NA         beer  single
```

What would be the relevant pivot_wider approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need to pivot longer, filter, *then* pivot wider:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(reg, -c(name, email), names_pattern = "(.*)[0-9]+$", 
             names_to = ".value") %>%
  filter(!is.na(option)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "option", values_from = "value")
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#   name  email               meal       drink room  
#   <chr> <chr>               <chr>      <chr> <chr> 
# 1 John  john@john.com       vegetarian NA    NA    
# 2 Bill  bill@acme.com       vegetarian beer  single
# 3 Chuck chuck@someplace.org NA         beer  single
```

Comment: Well, it works (and even on my real case !), thanks a mil !